# Map an array and search google with node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a json document that contains an array that I'm able to loop through.

I'm getting the right data back, but not at the right now. I guess this is where async comes into play.

This is my code:

```
import data from '../data.json';
import google from 'google';

google.resultsPerPage = 1



data.sitesToScrape.map((site, i) => {
  let name = site.name
  let state = site.states

  google(name, (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    res.links.map((link, err) => {

      if (err) console.error(err);

      console.log(link.href)
    });

  })

  console.log(name,state)
});
```

and my console output:

```
4-County Electric Power Assn MS
ACTON WATER DISTRICT OFFICE MA
http://www.actonwater.com/customer-service/contact-us
1
null
http://www.4county.org/
```

What is the right way of doing this? I need to understand async better :(

Comment: What is your actual question? The right way of doing things depends on your expected outcome. What do you think/want to happen?

Comment: I would just like clean data back. In this case being the href. But I think since it's taking time to grab the data from the json file, I'm getting a null response within the loop.

Comment: @Ben I think the google module is running before it has a chance to receive the data.

Comment: Are you able to provide a working example in a fiddle? It'd make it a lot easier to see what's happening. You might also want to add some clarity/detail to the question like your expected console output.